# Drupal to Wordpress migration formatting cleanup

Tags: wordpress, drupal

I've migrated a clients site from Drupal to WordPress and I'm having some trouble with formatting of the old posts. 
Somehow posts are remembering their automatic Read More break points from Drupal, and text formatting. Font sizes in posts are now anywhere between 12px and 32px. 
On the home page of the new site I will show posts in boxes with limited space and i really need the text to break where I want it. the_excerpt() function where I limited the length works only for newly added posts.

I've tried SQL queries like 
`UPDATE wordpress.wp_posts
    SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,'%<!--break-->%','')
;` 
and a WP plugin called Search & Replace to find and eliminate `<!--break-->, <p></p>, <br />` with no success.

Does anyone have any ideas on how this could be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved...
I used this: `UPDATE wp_posts SET post_excerpt = '';` 
I really don't know how I didn't realize sooner that post_excerpt column was filled during migration. This also fixed the font size...